# Another "can't mount USB" question, tried prev. answers but still doesn't work

Tags: usb, mount, mp3-player

Please forgive yet another "I can't mount a USB drive", but the output doesn't match what previous threads seem to assume.

**the device:** USB mp3-player of the simplest type. Just a USB stick with headphone jack.

**what happened:** Mac crashed whilst it was mounted. Now Mac will see it but won't read or format it, windows won't even see it, and Linux will chirrup when it is plugged in or removed but it doesn't mount.

**what I've tried:**(caveat: I'm only a basic user, more comfortable with hardware than software) From previous threads I've understood that the following can be of interest.

With the usb plugged in `ls -l /dev/* | wc -l` give `500`, unplugged the I get `492`.

In Disks it is noted as being

"Model" *USB 2.0 Boot Loader (0001)*

"Serial Number" *USB_2.0_Boot_Loader-0:0*

"Device" */dev/sdb*

the rest are just -, and the "Edit Mount Options" has the automount has ON. With the usb plugged in, i can conrfirm this with

```
r@Sammy ~ $ ls /dev/ | grep sd
sda
sda1
sda2
sda3
sda4
sda5
sda6
sda7
sdb
```

because unplugged I get

```
r@Sammy ~ $ ls /dev/ | grep sd
sda
sda1
sda2
sda3
sda4
sda5
sda6
sda7
```

however, lsblk doesn't find it

```
r@Sammy ~ $ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0    20G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0  83.3G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  46.7G  0 part /
├─sda6   8:6    0   2.8G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda7   8:7    0  80.1G  0 part /home
```

Similarly, fdisk doesn't see it

```
r@Sammy ~ $ sudo fdisk -l 

Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc9af158c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    41945087    20971520   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2   *    41945088    42149887      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        42149888   216739839    87294976    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       216741886   488396799   135827457    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       216741888   314566106    48912109+  83  Linux
/dev/sda6       314566656   320430079     2931712   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       320432128   488396799    83982336   83  Linux
```

Using the same plug-unplug method lsusb gives tells me that it is called AliCorp, this is the printout with it plugged in

```
r@Sammy ~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0ac8:c33f Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. Webcam
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0402:7103 ALi Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

The verbose output for the device is

```
r@Sammy ~ $ lsusb -v

Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0402:7103 ALi Corp. 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0402 ALi Corp.
  idProduct          0x7103 
  bcdDevice            0.01
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                1 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
```

and `dmesg's tail looks thus:

```
r@Sammy ~ $ dmesg | tail
[ 1445.792288] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 1445.926150] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=0402, idProduct=7103
[ 1445.926166] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 1445.926177] usb 1-7: Product: ALi USB 2.0 BOOT LOADER
[ 1446.281913] usb-storage 1-7:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1446.282430] scsi4 : usb-storage 1-7:1.0
[ 1446.282744] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 1447.281479] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USB 2.0  Boot Loader           PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 1447.282860] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 1447.285217] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Obviously, I also tried mounting it manually

```
r@Sammy ~ $ sudo mount /dev/sdb /home/r/Desktop
mount: no medium found on /dev/sdb
```

As you've probably guessed, I don't really know what I'm doing, just parroting commands. My vague guess it that the problem is that the blockdevice sdb isn't assigned a file system, but I've no idea what that means or what to do about it. Ideas? doesn't matter if it formats the device and looses all the files, it would just be nice to have it working again.

Thanks for any suggestions and/or explanations about what's going on.

Comment: Boot your machine, have a coffee, log in, have another coffee (=wait for all disk activity to stop), open a terminal, insert the device and type:  ` dmesg | tail` and copy-paste the output of that into your question.  (we need more info)

Comment: Thanks Fabby for replying! Please find dmesg | tail added to the post above. The first time I plugged it in, waited a bit, then ran the cmd it didn't mention sdb or anything similiar, only wlan0. Unplugging and replugging in though gave the output above. Does it help explain what's going on?

Comment: OK, what's the output of `lsblk` after you do `sudo mount /mnt /dev/sdb1 -o uid=1000` ? what `ls -l /mtn` tells you ?

Comment: Thanks Serg for taking an interest! The mount cmd you suggested said "mount point doesn't exist", but re-running the mount cmd in my post above with -o uid=1000 said "no medium found on /dev/sdb". `lsblk` after that looked identical to the one in my post above, and `ls -l /mnt` just says `total 0`. FWIW, pls note I've added `dmesg | tail` to the post following the q from Fabby.

Comment: The thing is totally broken...  Do me a favour: take the largest hammer you can find and smash it and post a picture.  That way everyone who tried helping you will get *some* satisfaction!  ;-)

Comment: Bleep! I was hoping it wasn't that, last time it crashed like this I got it back. <sigh> RIP little mp3 player...  Thanks all for diagnosing this for me!

Answer (score 0):

Its name doesn't have to start with "sd". Open GParted, select you mp3 player as device and choose "Device" → "Create Partition Table ..." to create a new Partition Table. By default, the right type for you is selected, just confirm. Then right-click on the empty storage space is shows you to create a new partition.

This will destroy your data. If you want to rescue your data, you can try it by using `testdisk`. Install it, open it from the terminal with `sudo testdisk`, select your MP3 player, select "Intel" and and search for partitions. If you are finished copying the files, exit testsdisk and do the above.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try GParted as soon as I get home, I don't care about the data, it's replaceable. I don't understand what you mean by "it doesn't have to start with sd" thought? I only thought it was sdb because that is what it says in Disks.

Comment: I've just tried it, but GParted only lists the same devices as fdisk, i.e. there is no USB memory  to choose as "Device", neither in the list or the drop-down thingy in the top-right corner. What else can I try please?